# How to validate windows password with cmd or python?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, passwords

Is there any way to validate windows password with cmd or python ?

My approach using cmd:

```
C:\users\username>net user USERNAME - mypassword
True
C:\users\username>net user USERNAME - pass
False
```

An example of what I'd like in python:

```
>>> import win32api
>>> win32api.password.check(mypassword)
True
>>> win32api.password.check(pass)
False
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Have a look at `os.system` or `os.popen` to execute system commands.

Comment: @Philipp I know these but what about cmd command?

Comment: I think **cmd** will not have function to validate windows password , because anyone could hack password then _( maybe )_.

Comment: @MuhammadNouman `cmd` is actually just the name of the program that runs your handy little application called `Command Prompt` :)

Comment: Does your `cmd` approach work?